# Datetime conversion exception with GeoServer and MySQL plugin 2.23.2

Tags: geoserver, mysql, datetime

After recently upgrading my database server from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0.31, I have updated the GeoServer in my project with the latest version 2.23.2 and the corresponding MySQL connector.

After this I got the following Java exception for every feature containing a non-null `DATETIME` value among the properties:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to class java.util.Date (java.time.LocalDateTime and java.util.Date are in module java-base of loader 'boostrap') class

The column's data type is [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html). I know that between MySQL version 5.7 and 8 there are changes in date and time handling, but I checked my data and found out that all of the values are either `NULL` or a valid `DATETIME`. (I also tried several connection parameters to allow zero dates and / or convert these to null, it did not help.)

After searching for similar issues I tried a lot of suggestions, and it was mentioned that downgrading `mysql-connector-java` to version 8.0.22 solves this issue.

So the original MySQL plugin 2.23.2 contained:

- `gt-jdbc-mysql-29.2`
- `mysql-connector-java-8.0.28`

After the downgrade I have these:

- `gt-jdbc-mysql-25.6`
- `mysql-connector-java-8.0.22`

The conversion exception is gone now, but I am not totally happy with this because it is just a workaround, some vulnerabilities were fixed with the latest `mysql-connector-java` and upgrading can be problematic later with this current setup.

I am aware of the the MySQL extension is unmaintained, but still, the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/data/database/mysql.html) clearly says:

> Warning Ensure to match plugin (example 2.24-SNAPSHOT above) version to the version of the GeoServer instance.

Has anyone experienced similar issues and is there a more reliable solution to solve this problem?

**EDIT 1:**

The full stacktrace is:

```
23 Aug 08:53:47 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] -
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to class java.util.Date (java.time.LocalDateTime and java.util.Date are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.encodeSimpleFeatures(GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.java:456)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.writeFeatures(GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.java:205)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.json.GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.write(GeoJSONGetFeatureResponse.java:149)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.write(WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.java:199)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1018)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.FailedRequestFilter.doFilter(FailedRequestFilter.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.HTTPMethodFilter.doFilter(HTTPMethodFilter.java:36)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilterInternal(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Are you running with `java-8.0.22`? Recent versions of GeoServer expect Java 11

Comment: I have JDK11, from [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/87870e3c459c6a29385662a4ad41c179a6f5166b/9.0/jdk11/temurin-focal/Dockerfile). I think `8.0.22` is not Java version, but `mysql-connector-java` version.

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks for the comment, see my answer above.

Comment: Well we have an online test that is apparently passing for this - https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/3553a627de870bb7b0c347da271ad148dab988f3/modules/plugin/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/src/test/java/org/geotools/data/mysql/MySQLTemporalFilterOnlineTest.java#L21 - can you add the full stacktrace, please

Comment: @IanTurton I will make a deploy with verbose logging and add the full stacktrace tomorrow.

Comment: @IanTurton I added the full stacktrace to my question.

Comment: OK that looks like a bug, it seems that the MySQL extension is passing LocalDateTime out and the WFS encoder is expecting only a Date. Off the top of my head I can't say who is wrong. Can you file an issue at https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/GEOS/issues

Comment: @IanTurton Thank you very much for your help. I will file the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue in an older Geoserver version; had a bit of debugging at that time and it looked like Geotools were expecting java.util.Date but the new driver returned LocalDateTime (it involved some kind of String representation also from my memory). The hack was to put mysql-connector-java-5.x.x.jar - worked for us.

Comment: Thank you, I know that it works with 5.x version of the connector, I also use that.I wanted to upgrade to version 8 when I faced this bug.